# make dex file from framework.jar

Tags: java, android, command-line, jar, dex

I receive dex format of framework.jar file so in command-line I type this command

"dx --dex -JXmx512m --no-strict "out.dex" "framework.jar" "

[image]

I should mention that when I use this command for another jar file I receive same error but when I use the command

"dx --dex --no-strict "out.dex" "test.jar" "

for another jar file(test.jar), out.dex file created, but this command doesn't work well for framework.jar and when I use this command I got this error

[image]

I want ask what is the problem?

Comment: It's much better to post the errors as text, rather than images. Images can't be searched or otherwise interacted with in a textual manner.

Comment: oh,that's true, good point.I keep this advise for my future question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `--output=out.dex` option to the command.

You can find information about other supported options by typing : 
`dx --help`

Also, if the jar file is large, you'll have to increase the heap size allocated to `dx`, in order to avoid the `OutOfMemoryError`. You can do this by passing the -JXmx option, or by editing the dx.bat/dx.sh file in the build tools directory of your android sdk.